# Suggestion technology/design on this BIGDATA usecase

Tags: hadoop, lucene, mapreduce, cassandra, bigdata

I am new to big data technologies and design so looking for help from java world.

I have concept of tags and tagcombinations.
For example U.S.A and Pen are two tags AND if they come together in some definition then register a tagcombination(U.S.A-Pen) for that..

tags (U.S.A, Pen, Pencil, India, Shampoo)
tagcombinations(U.S.A-Pen, India-pencil, U.S.A-Pencil, India-Pen, India-Pen-Shampoo)

- millions of tags
- billions of tagcombinations
- one tagcombination generally have 2-8 tags....
- Every day we get lakhs of new tagcombinations to write
- daily crores of queries to find matching combination by set of tags

Query need to support :
one tag or set of tags appears in how many tagcombinationids ????
If i query for Pen,India then it should return two tagcombinaions (India-Pen, India-Pen-Shampoo))..Query will be fired by application in realtime.

Please suggest a solution which is distributed with java client and can
handle scale of data  i am looking for..

Already tried on cassandra but not able toconclude that as right match for my problem..

Thanks
Naresh

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into Apache Lucene project:

http://lucene.apache.org/

You won't be able to use Cassandra directly for this but if you store your data inside Cassandra, you can use Solr to add extra indexes on top of your data. DataStax has a bundle solution called DataStax Enterprise that has Cassandra/Solr together:

http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise

Comment: thanks much..from my research i was also reaching there...DSE cannot go with it as licenesed..i cam across a project lucandra which stores lucene in cassandra column family...any feeback on this or similar solutions ????

Comment: DataStax Enterprise is free of charge for development purposes.